# Bootstrap auto grid row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, html-lists

everyone.
I need an advise. I am new in it.
I have li element.

```
<li class="list-group-item py-4 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ form.about_yourself.label }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <strong> {{ person.about_yourself }} </strong>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="{% url 'get_phone' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" > Change </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have got this (picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exdoU.png) 
But I wanna have no space between rows.In another words, I wanna rows have auto size, like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29qm7.png) 
Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use col-md and col-md-auto for fit-to-width...

```
<li class="list-group-item py-4 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-auto"> about_yourself </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt codeply</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm"> Change </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

https://codeply.com/p/ZRAOBTGgNC